# Есть ли программы для приведения кода к нормальному стилю?

Tags: c, java, c++

Нужна программа для форматирования кода, из криворукого к стандарту. Есть ли такие программы? Желательно, чтобы можно было разом всю директорию перелопатить. Хотелось бы поддержку языков C,C++ и Java.

например было

```
if(1>0){return 0;}else{return 1;}
```

стало

```
if(1>0)
{
    return 0;
}
else 
{
    return 1;
}
```

или к любому другому нормальному стилю.
Никакие среды разработки не используются, просто нужно преобразовать файлы.

Comment: Любая современная IDE с этим справится)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть, называются бьютифаер (beautifier).

Запрос в поисковик "beautifier %язык%" выдаст множество таких, к примеру [uncrustify](http://freecode.com/projects/uncrustify) или [Universal Indent GUI](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Чего то не смог найти, а консоль uncrustify под windows 7 сразу закрывается.

Comment: Эм. Так и запускайте из шелла, если я верно понял вашу проблему.

Comment: бред. Зачем под это отдельную утилиту? IDE для этих языков имеют прекрасные бьюфатеры

Comment: @voipp любите работать руками? "Наши руки не для скуки"? Хм.

Answer (score 1):

Скачиваешь программу [Artistic Style](http://sourceforge.net/projects/astyle/files/). Из всего zip-архива реально нужен только файл bin/AStyle.exe, распакуй его куда-нибудь (у меня для таких мелких полезняшек папочка C:\UTIL предназначена, например).

- Потом создай ярлык на эту программу, добавь опции --style=kr --recursive *.c* .h
- Или, например, --style=allman --recursive *.cpp* .hpp
- Или --style=java --recursive *.java

В зависимости от того, какой язык используется и какой [стиль](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2) ты предпочитаешь. Потом кладешь этот ярлык в каталог с исходниками и будет именно так, как сказал NMD: щелкаем мышкой на иконке и происходит чудо!

Кстати, сам я этой программой уже не пользуюсь. Гораздо лучше привыкнуть сразу писать код нормально оформленный. И самый лучший помощник в этом - редактор [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/). Но если нужно часто разгребать чужой код, тогда да, такие программы, как AStyle, полезны.

Answer (score 0):

- C/C++ — [Vera](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Home), [google c++lint](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cpplint/cpplint.py), [Uncrustify](http://freecode.com/projects/uncrustify), etc. Вообще, для C/C++ подобного добра навалом, с разной степенью глючности и функциональности, так что выбирайте, что лучше подойдёт именно вам.
- Java — [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/), конечно же. Имхо, конкурентов у него нет.

Comment: ни vera++, ни Uncrustify не работают. На windows 7 не запускаются.
Мне нужно разом отформатировать около 1500 файлов, по одному не вариант)

Comment: Попробуйте indent. Если будут затруднения с вопросом, как его натравить на Ваши полторы тысячи файлов -- пишите.

Comment: @Billy Milligan, я так понимаю слова "документация" и "работа с командной строкой" для Вас ничего не значат? Не все программы работают с визуальным интерфейсом.

Comment: как раз не могу разобраться как всю директорию отформатировать)
не подскажите?

Comment: @Alex Krass, я вижу что чтение не для вас, командная строка закрывается, повторю ещё раз

Comment: @Billy Milligan, hint: `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @Billy Milligan, я правильно понимаю, что вы открывали CMD. Потом в ней находили свою директорию и вызывали в ней тот же Uncrustify:

> c:\filesdirectory> "%path%\uncrustify.exe" -c *.c

И у Вас не выдавалось ни ошибок, ничего, а просто закрывалась как сама программа, так и основная консоль CMD?

Comment: Наверное все было иначе:
просто запуск uncrustify.exe и ожидание чуда))

Comment: @Alex Krass, нет я думал что команды нужно вводить в открывшейся строке. Первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь. Я думал запущу exe и там вбивать буду.

Comment: @Billy Milligan, не сочтите за грубость, просто подталкиваю Вас на верные мысли. Вышеозначенные программы работают через вызов из командный строки, с передачей им нужный опций (-c -c++ -line-indent etc) и самих файлов(\*.c \*.cpp) и тому подобное. Еще в них есть конфигурационные файлы. Все это описано в документации к программам и простыми приложениями они не являются. 

Если не охота возиться с такими трудностями, можете попробовать попросить конкретной помощи или использовать IDE с уже встроенными  такими возможностями.

Comment: @Alex Krass про IDE ТС уже писал -- 1500 файлов. Ручная работа. И нехилая. А вот find в сочетании с форматизатором -- самое то.

Comment: @Billy Milligan, @falstaf ну bash поставить не проблема, но в cmd.exe есть команда for (в отличие от древнего command.com)

    Z:\>for /?
    FOR используется для применения заданной <команды> для одного файла или набора файлов.

    Синтаксис: FOR %переменная IN (набор) DO команда

Comment: Добавлю.

      for %i in (*.c) do z:\usr\bin\indent -linux %i

Как-то так. На `z:\` не обращайте внимания -- wine (логотип -- рюмка с красненьким)

Comment: @alexlz, я имел ввиду попробовать найти IDE или специализированные программы, которые позволяют сделать пакетную обработку всех файлов в проекте. Хотя в их существование я не уверен.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [clang_format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html). У него даже есть интеграция с Visual Studio, правда в alpha-версии.

Answer (score -2):

Вот хорошая программка phpstorm, там php, JavaScript, css, C, html и др.

Comment: > Никакие среды разработки не используются, просто нужно преобразовать файлы.

Comment: @cas-live Вам понятно, за что минусовали? А можно ещё вспомнить пользователя-героя (из Кенгуленда?), который быстро-быстро обработал 500 картинок в фотошопе (как у него мыша не задымилась?). А потом парень стал получать заманчивые предложения работы.

Comment: @Alex Krass Отвечаю здесь, там комментарии кончились. Такие вещи вполне могут существовать, но с немалой вероятностью это -- тренировочные поделия юных пионЭров, поскольку никому другому это не надо. Соответственно и искать их я большого смысла не вижу. Разве что для преподавателей, которые мучаются в раздумьях, как своих студентов озадачить (а придумать подходящую задачу для лабораторной-ргр-куросовой совсем непросто)